# how do i get time from .log file with date and time powershell

Tags: powershell, date, time

```
2022.10.23 08:27:01.829 | INFO | Request finished in 3.892ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
2022.10.23 08:27:05.044 | DBUG | Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 4 items
2022.10.23 08:27:05.044 | DBUG | Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0048ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 4 items
2022.10.23 23:31:05.097 | INFO | Request finished in 9.0403ms 202 
2022.10.23 08:27:15.052 | DBUG | Starting HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle with 4 items
2022.10.23 08:27:15.052 | DBUG | Ending HttpMessageHandler cleanup cycle after 0.0022ms - processed: 0 items - remaining: 4 items
2022.10.23 00:27:01.544 | INFO | Request finished in 3.8349ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
2022.10.23 00:42:01.551 | INFO | Request finished in 4.7531ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I got .log files with lines like this. I need to get the time and date in a table like this. I had to filter out and count how many lines with "ms 200", "ms 202", "ms 400" etc. are there and find the file where they are.
This is my working code:

```
$logpath = "C:\Users\matus\OneDrive\Desktop\praca\PosybeRestEPService\*.log"

Get-ChildItem $logpath -Filter *.log | 
Foreach-Object {
Select-String -Path  $_.FullName  -Pattern '(?<=\d.*?ms )(2|3|4|5)\d+' | 
Group-Object -Property { $_.Matches.Value } | 
    Select-Object -Property Count, Name, @{
        Name = 'Filename'
        Expression = { $_.Group[0].Filename }
    }

}
```

I got the right output:

```
Count Name Filename                           
----- ---- --------                           
   68 202  PosybeRestEPService20221020.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221020.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221021.log
   34 202  PosybeRestEPService20221021.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221022.log
  149 202  PosybeRestEPService20221022.log
    1 400  PosybeRestEPService20221022.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221023.log
    1 202  PosybeRestEPService20221023.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221024.log
  165 202  PosybeRestEPService20221024.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221025.log
   32 202  PosybeRestEPService20221025.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221026.log
  154 202  PosybeRestEPService20221026.log
   96 200  PosybeRestEPService20221027.log
   92 202  PosybeRestEPService20221027.log
```

Now i need to write day and time when these "ms 200", "ms 202", "ms 400" occurred.
I tried something like this:

```
$errors = @($logpath | Where-Object { $_ -match '^\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*Errors:' } |   
                    Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null) }).Count
```

Comment: See following : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fce1c36c-0573-4242-81be-05cce750bf9a/formating-the-result-of-selectobject?forum=ITCG&force_isolation=true

Comment: Did you forget to write the last half of this question? You tried extracting the date information from the log file name and then what? Did it produce the wrong output? Throw an error? What happens? :)

Comment: It throws an error

Comment: Then kindly post the error and tell us what exactly you are looking out of it? @Gaara

Comment: I deleted my answer since I don't know what the expected output is. Since it's a grouped object, you are only working with one matched line. So, if you want to get the date would it just be for that single line? Each name property (`200`,`202`,`xxx`,etc.) has a unique date, so which date are you looking to grab if you're only showing 1 property per line matched; in other words, `202`  is found across multiple files with multiple dates. Also, is `2022.10.23 08:27:01.829` what you're trying to match?

Comment: sorry, it apparently doesn't throw an error. it does nothing. I have to write out times (I assume 08:27:01.829 for example) when these gropus ("ms200" "ms 202" etc) occured. So I think my output for for this output line " 68 202  PosybeRestEPService20221020.log" should be 68 different times when did "ms 202" occur.

Comment: @Gaara, can you update your post to clarify the above? Also, if you can include an example of what the result should look like with your current output.

Comment: I dont really know how should it look, just got instructions thats it. But this is the final Output I should have. Exported to .csv with delimiter ";" : PosybeRestEPService20220913.log;200;96x;202;49x; (log filename; number of error; how many times did the error happened)

Comment: @Gaara, techinically, your current output is a bit wrong then. Since those patterns are matched across multiple files, you should have a list of file names under `FileName` because it was found in all of those. Without seeing what your expected output is including the date, there's not much I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps after something more along the lines of:

```
$logpath = "C:\Users\matus\OneDrive\Desktop\praca\PosybeRestEPService\*.log"
Select-String -Path $logpath -Pattern '(?<=\d.*?ms )(2|3|4|5)\d+' | 
    Group-Object -Property { $_.Matches.Value } | 
    Select-Object -Property Count, Name, @{
        Name = 'Filename'
        Expression = { $_.Group.Filename -join ', ' }
    },@{
        Name = 'Date'
        Expression = { 
            ($_.Group.Line | 
                ForEach-Object -Process {
                    $_ -match '^.*?(?=\|)' | Out-Null
                    [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[0].Trim(),'yyyy.M.d HH:mm:ss.fff',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
                } 
            ) -join ', '
        } 
    }
```

The pattern `'^.*?(?=\|)'` is somewhat of a cheat as it's just matching the beginning text all the way up to the first `|`. Since that's the whole date, you can use the `datetime` class method of `ParseExact` to convert it over to a `datetime` object.

This should output the file names that those patterns were matched along with the dates all separated by a comma (`,`). Now, the output is something like:

```
Count Name Filename            Date                                                              
----- ---- --------            ----                                                              
    3 200  1.txt, 2.txt, 7.txt 9/20/2020 1:42:01 PM, 10/21/2022 1:42:01 PM, 10/20/2022 1:42:01 PM
    2 400  3.txt, 6.txt        11/20/2022 1:42:01 PM, 10/20/2022 1:42:01 PM                      
    1 300  4.txt               10/20/2020 13:42:01                                               
    1 500  5.txt               10/20/2022 13:42:01
```